# PHP script for adding friends

Tags: php, mysql, database

Well I'm trying for last 5 days to create simple register, confirm, login PHP script, which is for assignment at UNI, but thing which I'm trying for last 5 days and it's not working is adding friends into friend list. Kid a like Facebook but much much simpler, it's for Android game we got as group assignment.

I have one `TABLE users` where I have fields `ID, username, password, email, friends`.

Into field friends I would like to save multiple values as ID's of your friends. To retrieve in game some of user information.

This db and tables are on MySQL and `INSERT` or `UPDATE` are not working for me, `INSERT` is creating new record and can't insert only to one column of existing record and `UPDATE` can't just insert value but will delete old one and insert new one in.

Comment: what code are you using, what results are you expecting and why, and what result do you get//what errors do you get?

Comment: 'Not working' is too vague - get any error messages? Are you checking mysql_error() or similar to see what the issue might be? Are you using the mysql module, mysqli, or pdo_mysql? Can we see the relevant bits of your code?

Comment: If you read a question such as this, how would  you help the person out without seeing a single line of code?

Comment: In general, I wouldn't put multiple ids into a single column (though there are some limited use cases). It would be better - especially if this is a study assignment - to have another table "has_friend" which has columns (friend_from_id, friend_to_id). You can insert every friend relation into this table, so each user has several related records.

Comment: UPDATE deletes an old record? How do you mean that? Also you should normalize your tables, in a way the field friends will become a foreign key of a [n:m relation](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html) to the user table itself, using a separate relation table.

Comment: As confusing as the question may look, I found it pretty understandable of what he's trying to achieve. Don't think those down-votes were necessary. In my opinion.

Comment: @Rick Kuipers Everyone understands WHAT he wnats to achieve, but not what he has done yet, to fullfill his task.

Comment: @feeela I see, but when talking about databases, it's not always about the "doing", it's mostly thinking which he tried to explain in his last paragraph. All he needs is a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as this is a many-to-many relation (if I'm correct) so it'd be smart to create a seperate table that records this.

```
Table: Friends
userID
userID2 (or friendID)
```

Which you can fill.

For more info: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx

Comment: @JakubZak No problem, now you know that what you're trying to achieve is a many to many relationship, just google some articles on it and it will help you a lot. Very common to use.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would add a freinds table with the fields:

user_id
friend_id

where both fields are references to the user tables id field.

If you - for some reason - need it to be a field in user table serialize the id values and save them there.

ATTENTION: you won't be able to easily join the tables and there is no automated possibility to keep integrity. If a user is deleted none of the references to this user in friends field will be deleted. This would all be possibile with the secondary friends table and foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described here is a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between people and their friends. The canonical way do implement this in a relational database is to use a pivot table in which each row represents a "friendship" between two people. You'd have two fields to hold the IDs:

`users` table:

```
id, name, email, etc.
```

`friendships` table:

```
user_id_1, user_id_2
```

Then if user 1 is friends with user 2 and user 3, you'd have records `(1,2)` and `(1,3)` in the `friendships` table. You can treat these as reciprocal relationships if you like, or you can require a `(2,1)` record to denote that user 2 is also friends with user 1.

Comment: so lost man, I'm completely lost in this. Have no idea how to do that. But thx anyway. Don't understand how it would work.

Comment: @Jakub Zak, understanding many-to-many relationships can be complicated at first. Simply read a few articles and tutorials about it and all will become clear.